# DFA diagram to recognize arithmetic expressions

Tags: math, operators, diagram, dfa

I need to draw a DFA diagram that can recognize arithmetic expressions, varialbes or brackets are not allowed. It can only contain numbers and four arithmetic operators.

And it has to accepts any number string with or without sign - e.g. 5, -7 , +15.
And the numbers strings can be mixed with arithmetic operators - e.g. 3+5 , -1+7*3.

I don't know if my diagram actually performs this requirements.

[image: DFA Diagram]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service.. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical programming but rather belongs on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No, your diagram is not good enough yet: it allows `+/-/+++` as an expression.

I'd start formulating this using something like [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) first, then turn that into a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (essentially inlining the non-terminals), and then [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) a DFA from that.

What is a number? Only integers, or can you have a decimal point? If decimal points are fine, do you need digits before and after, or just one of them? Do you allow scientific notation with "e" in it? May there be leding zeros in numbers, or only if the whole integer part is zero? And what about signs? Do you allow more than one? Do you allow an unary plus or minus sign after any arithmetic operator?

Depending on your answers above, the EBNF might look somewhat like this:

```
digits     = digit { digit }
number     = [ "+" | "-" ] ( digits [ "." [ digits ] ] | "." digits )
operator   = "+" | "-" | "*" | "/"
expression = number { operator number }
```

Turning these things to regular expressions:

```
digits    : [0-9]+
number    : [+\-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)
operator  : [+\-*/]
expression: [+\-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)([+\-*/][+\-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+))*
```

Now that final regexp is what you can use to build a DFA from. May it have ε transitions or do you need inputs on all edges? Must it be deterministic? Depending on these answers, there may be more or less work ahead of you.

You don't have to mechanically turn the regexp ino an automaton; with a bit of human intuition you can build a simpler automaton. But make sure that you see all the considerations which are captured in the building of these expressions reflected in your automaton. Avoid allowing more than one decimal point. Avoid chaining operators. Make sure every number has at least one digit. Things like this.